# The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions

Tags: vb.net, transactions

I have some code which is doing something like this (please note that the actual code is much more complex).  I have produced this to aid explanation:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Transactions

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Using scope As New TransactionScope
            Try
                Dim objCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Connection string 1")
                Dim objCon2 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Connection string 2")
                objCon2.Open()
                Using objCon2
                    Dim t1 As New Test
                    t1.Test()
                    objCon.Open()
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
              'I do not swallow exceptions
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Test
    Public Sub Test()
        Dim objCon1 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Connection string 1")
        objCon1.Open()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The code above shows that I am connecting to two databases inside the transaction (one of them is connected to twice).  Here is the exception: FormLoad error: System.Transactions.TransactionException: The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025).

Answer (score 0):

See this SO post. The guy finds the answer to his question, and so much more.

[transactionscope-with-multiple-database-connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218867/error-linq-transactionscope-with-multiple-database-connections)

Definately a good read if working with TransactionScope.