# Correct way to use DbConnection, DbTransaction with connection pooling, transactionScope and dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, repository-pattern, transactionscope, system.data, system.data.oracleclient

I have a Oracle database and I'm using the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`.

In some cases I will need to do actions in a single transactions, but often not.

I'm not sure what the best way to handle `DbConnection` objects within a single `TransactionScope`.

I could inject a `DbConnection` into the repositories and then even use `LifetimePerScope` to ensure they all get the same `DbConnection` instance. But is that a smart move, is it ok to `.Open()` the connection once.

```
using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var connection = scope.Resolve<IDbConnection>();
    var personRepo = scope.Resolve<IPersonRepository>();
    var workRepo = scope.Resolve<IWorkRepository>();
    connection.Open();
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
    personRepo.DeleteById(someId);
    workRepo.DeleteByPersonId(someId);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

This would force me to always use a `LifetimeScope`, even if not using a Transaction, and open the connection outside the repository method.

Are TransactionScopes dependent on a single connection or can I open multiple connections (how does the connectionPool handle that while a transaction is open?) within the same transaction?

I'm a total outsider to DbConnections and all that so I might be totally misunderstanding the best way to use TransactionScope and DbConnections.

Answer (score 3):

Possible duplicate of: [Why always close Database connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111594/why-always-close-database-connection)

Since this has a bounty, I can't flag it as a duplicate :(

Anyway, connection pooling is largely done for you.  You should close connections as soon as you can, to return them to the pool.

Transactions are related to a specific open connection and should be finished when closing the connection.

Answer (score 2):

TransactionScope related to BeginTransaction() is specific to a connection.
If you want to maintain a transaction across multiple connections(multiple DBs,resources), then you need [DTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Distributed_Transaction_Coordinator) aware [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is a similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218867/error-linq-transactionscope-with-multiple-database-connections).  You need to use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll` to facilitate that.

You might want to go through these links:

1.[All about transactionscope](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope)

2.[How To Configure DTC to Support Oracle Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344212(v=vs.85).aspx)

Hope this helps.